# C++ Returning a Count

Tags: c++

Can someone help me understand what does it mean to return a count?
I know the function involves a for-loop or a while-loop depending on the situation but I'm having trouble understanding the concept. I'll try to be as clear as possible.

Here's an example: I have two functions from a cryptography class: lock() and unlock(). They are polymorphic and they take no parameter and return no value. Does that mean the functions itself are blank?

And then I have another function encryptionLvl(). This one takes no parameter but they should return a count of the current number of encryption level, and that number should be incremented each time lock() is called and decremented each time unlock() is call.

How do I make this work?
Sorry if I'm confusing you. I'm a beginner at this programming, but I appreciate the effort.

Comment: I know [someone who can explain this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Count_von_Count).

Comment: Also a good place to start is the official [SO help page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Kerrek SB Come on, this is serious. -_-'

Comment: Please make sure you know the difference between `virtual int encryptionLvl() = 0;` and `virtual int encryptionLvl() { return 0; }`

Comment: @BenVoigt Reading through it now. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A function can take no parameter and return `void`. You can think of such a function as a procedure. Although there is not return value, a procedure can affect your program through side effects. Like this:

```
class Counter {
    int i;
public:
    void increment() { i = i + 1; }
    void reset() {
        i = 0;
        return; // The empty return statement is optional
    }
    int get() { return i; }
}
```

In your case, `lock()` does not return a value, but it increments the counter. `unlock()` does the opposite. `encryptionLvl()` is equivalent to `get()`.

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate it.